# Can Zend_Service_Rest do file uploads?

Tags: php, zend-framework, upload, rest

I assume that RESTful services is a comprehensive paradigm, that it also could cover file uploads too, as a subset of http operations.

If so, how does one do file uploads in Rest and specifically, with Zend_Service_Rest?

Should my client code somehow read the file and assign its content to some property of restful object? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to use `Zend_Service_Rest` to play with REST, having a simple controller and checking what verb has been used could also make it.

`Zend_Service_Rest` is just here to show one implementation but in my opinion the way of passing arguments is too restrictive. I prefer to code my own controller so I have more control.

if you are using `PUT` for uploading file you could do something like that

```
public function foobarAction(){
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender()
   if($request->isPut()){
      //DOSOMETHING with $_FILES 
   }
}
```